# Can any one explain ? How AccessDenied.aspx is calling in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I would like to redirect to sign in as different user page instead of AccessDenied.aspx. could any one please explain how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems in doing exactly what you want.

First, as far as I know, the ability to customize the access denied page and substitute it with a custom one is only provided at Web Application level. This means that all the site collections hosted by the web application you are configuring will experience the custom behavior. Before proceeding further ensure this seem reasonable.

Second, the "Sign In as different user" link  was removed from SharePoint interface because of some problems it caused with older browsers (seem to recall there was some security issue involved). There are multiple ways to restore it, but that seem to go against Microsoft practices as stated by   this official [KB article mentioning it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2752600) *suggesting that users should instead use the "Run As Different User" functionality provided by the operating system*. I would try to avoid using that page if you have other alternatives.

That said, there is a PowerShell command you can use to switch the default access denied page to a custom one:

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -Identity AccessDenied -WebApplication "webApp" 
                        -RelativePath "customAccessDeniedRelativeUrl"
```

The relative path to the original "Sign As Different User" page should be

`"/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true"`

There is a last warning though: SharePoint expects a custom access denied page to be accessible from unauthorized users. This implies at least two prerequisites:

- it should avoid pointing to a masterpage using a logical path like `~masterurl` or other dynamic master page approach. This basically leaves you with `MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/simple.master"`
- the page should be accessible everywhere and without need for authorization. This will probably translate to a layout folder page that inherits from `UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase`

Before proceeding further you should ensure that the old "Sign As Different User" meets this prerequisites. I would see at least two user case that you should try and test before committing to this approach:

1. check that an unauthenticated user can still sing in to the site.
2. check that an authenticated user trying to access to a resource he isn't authorized to access is redirected to the expected page.

If these basic check fail, then your best bet is to try and develop a custom login page that you can substitute to the default access denied page. There should be enough resource to get started in custom SharePoint sign in pages both on MSDN and here on SE, but fell free to ask another question if you should find yourself stuck.

Comment: Could you please explain how default access denied page is calling from layouts in SharePoint 2013. I would like to know exactly where tat AccessDenied.aspx is calling

Comment: Sorry, not sure of what you exactly mean here, @chitra. You mean how to redirect to the default AccessDenied.aspx page from a custom one in the _layout folder? Or how the default AccessDenied is loaded from SharePoint?/where you can find it in the _layout folder? Can you please try to rephrase the question? I will try and see what I can find out, but as now I am having some difficulties in understanding what information you are seeking.

Comment: how the default AccessDenied is loaded from SharePoint? this is my exact question